# Jquery extend time

Tags: jquery, html

Hey guys am new to jquery and i need to add the time limit to my loading image.Its a gif file..My code is

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<script>$(document).ready(function(){
  var imagename=$("#name").val();
  $("#back").hide();
  $("form").submit(function(event){
    $("#data").hide();
    $("#image").show();

    $("#image").html('<br/><br/><img src="fuck.gif" width="100" height="100"/><br/><br/><br/>Loading Image ...');
    $.post( "images.php", $( "#data" ).serialize(),function(data){
       $("#image").show();
       $("#back").show(10000);
       $("#image").html("<img src='images.php'/>");} );
       event.preventDefault();
    });

    $("#back").click(function(){
      $("#back").hide();
      $("#image").html("By <b>Akash Sharma</b> (hsakapandit@gmail.com)");

      $("#data").show(10000);
    });
  });
</script>
```

When i use this code the image appear but it came in action only for 1 second when i tried adding the duration of the image by `$("#back").show(10000);` If anybody know how to add the time period more for the loading image please help me ..

Thanks in advance..

Comment: Your question is unclear.  What do you mean the the "image came in action only for 1 second"?   You mean it disappeared 1 second after it showed, or that whatever animation you set to have it showed only lasted a second?

Comment: @JTG it disappera after 1 sec

Answer (score 1):

`.show()` does not support any duration, it is instant.

You might be looking for `fadeIn()` or `animate()` instead.

```
$("#back").fadeIn( 10000 ); // 10000 milliseconds, or 10 seconds
```

http://api.jquery.com/fadein/

```
$("#back").animate({
    opacity: 1.00 // Identify the property to animate
}, 10000 ); // 10000 milliseconds, or 10 seconds
```

http://api.jquery.com/animate/

Either method will require you to set opacity = 0 on `#back` element prior to use, like:

```
$("#back").fadeTo( 1, 0.00 ); // Fade to 0% opacity, in 1 millisecond
```

OR like:

```
$("#back").css( "opacity", 0.00 );
```

Comment: I have made changes but the loading bar keeps going after 1 secong ..i have adjusted time settings to $("#back").animate({
    opacity: 1.00 // Identify the property to animate
}, 20000 ); but still the loading bar stays there only for 1 second

Comment: @set sail media ..it would be really helpful ...if you post the wholw code bro